# Outlook 2011 on OSX doesn't show notifications for filtered emails

Tags: macos, email, microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2011

I created a rule to immediately move new email to a folder in Outlook 2011 on OSX.

Whenever new  mail is received and it's sent to the folder via the rule, there is no desktop notification. Nothing that indicates I have new email. There is no number notification on the Outlook icon in the dock or anything.

From what I read, it appears that Outlook on Windows has the ability to add a "Display Desktop Notification" action to your rules. I don't see any option like this on OSX.

Is there any way to fix this issue? It really sucks when you are focused working and don't see an important email until it's too late simply because it was filtered to a folder and you got no notification of it arriving.